# HTTP Trigger using octet stream

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to create an Azure Functions HTTP trigger that uses application/octet-stream instead of application/json?

I currently have a trigger that for application/json.

Comment: You can make use of "application/json-data-stream" refer this SO thread here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301743/how-to-return-stream-of-data-from-azure-function-http

Comment: Also, You can directly change the binding to stream in function.json refer here - For languages that are dynamically typed such as JavaScript, use the dataType property in the function.json file. For example, to read the content of an HTTP request in binary format, set dataType to binary:

{
    "dataType": "binary",
    "type": "httpTrigger",
    "name": "req",
    "direction": "in"
}
Other options for dataType are stream and string.

Comment: Refer here - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings.md#trigger-and-binding-definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to stream the data in HTTP Trigger as stream:-

> According to this [**Github document**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings.md#trigger-and-binding-definitions), ***You can edit your function.json file of your HTTP Trigger with data type as binary or stream to stream the data*** like below:-

**function.json code:-**

```json
{

"generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator-4.1.1",

"configurationSource": "attributes",

"bindings": [

{

"type": "httpTrigger",

"direction": "in",

"dataType": "stream",

"route": "myroute",

"methods": [

"post"

],

"authLevel": "function",

"name": "req"

}

],

"disabled": false,

"scriptFile": "../bin/FunctionApp9.dll",

"entryPoint": "MyFunction.RunAsync"

}
```

[image]

> Additionally according to this [SO
> Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67301743/how-to-return-stream-of-data-from-azure-function-http) answer by Andy, By referring Andy's code, I got the below output in my browser after I ran the HTTP trigger:-
> **Here  response.ContentType is set to "application/json-data-stream";**
>
> ***Andy's Code:-***
> ***Function.cs:-***
>
> ```cs
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs; using
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http; using
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http; using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging; using
> Newtonsoft.Json; using System.Collections.Generic;
>
> namespace FunctionApp10 {
>     public class Function1
>     {
>         private async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetDataAsync()
>         {
>             for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
>             {
>                 yield return "{\"hello\":\"world\"}";
>             }
>         }
>
>         [FunctionName("Function1")]
>         public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
>             [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
>             ILogger log)
>         {
>             var response = req.HttpContext.Response;
>
>             await using var sw = new StreamWriter(response.Body);
>             await foreach (var msg in GetDataAsync())
>             {
>                 await sw.WriteLineAsync(msg);
>             }
>
>             await sw.FlushAsync();
>
>             response.StatusCode = 200;
>             response.ContentType = "application/json-data-stream";
>
>             return new EmptyResult();
>         }
>     }
>   }
> ```

**Output:-
Trigger got executed:-**

[image]

**Got streamed response in the Browser like below:-**

[image]